How is Numpy able to get an array size at run-time?
In C++ the size of an array must be determined at the compile-time.
I want to write a simple code in C++, say, to do a naive matrix multiplication with itself (for a matrix that is square in size) and I want to do it for any matrix size. However, I do not know how I can get the matrix sizes or the matrices of various sizes at the run-time in C++.
I have read that there are two types of memory, stack and heap. It seems the size of arrays on stack must be determined at the compile-time while the size of an array on heap can be determined at rune-time.
I also know that Numpy can get the size of an array from the user in Python and create an array in C/C++, so, the way Numpy do this might be the solution.
Does Numpy do compilation after getting the size of an array from the user? or are Numpy arrays created on the heap in C?
Basically, how does Numpy avoid this issue?
Edit
I changed the question to put the focus on how Numpy resolves the issue I had.

You want std::vector rather than a raw array, it can have its size set at runtime. (Uses new[] under the hood to achieve that.) It would also be a nice idea to use something like std::mdspan as your function parameter to be able to accept sub-matrices without copying them into new storage, but it's not supported in GCC yet.

"Does Numpy do compilation after getting the size of an array from the user?...." Python is almost always runtime.

Also the c++ standard has no notion of stack or heap. These are implementation details and should not matter for the most part. Just use std::vector if you want user to provide the size.

The size of an array must be know at compile time. For std::array that's true, for std::vector it is not.

@HolyBlackCat Do you happen to know what Numpy does? Does it also use std::vector?

@MOON Again that should not matter. It is all implementation details. Also, numpy is written in C so it can't use std::vector. Is your question "how numpy is implemented?". If yes, you can modify your question to directly ask that.

@MOON They either use malloc() or new[] (which are closely related). The point is that you (usually) have to allocate on the heap to be able to set the size at runtime.

@user12002570 People say that heap memory is slower than stack memory. Then std::vector will uses the slower heap memory. However, you mention that C++ does not know the difference.  So, in C++ we do not get slower performance due to heap memory or stack memory? right? since it seems there is not difference between these in C++.

"you mention that C++ does not know the difference" If you're talking about this "Also the c++ standard has no notion of stack or heap", this is mostly just a bit of (not very useful) trivia. Yes, the standard doesn't use those words, but it doesn't really matter, because everyone else does, and we're not talking specifically about the standard. The standard just calls them differently.

"People say that heap memory is slower than stack memory." Allocating/deallocating on heap is likely slower, but that's the tradeoff you pay for being able to set size at runtime. There are likely some tricks to reduce the cost, but you shouldn't worry about them until the performance actually becomes a problem.


Does Numpy do compilation after getting the size of an array from the user?

No, python and its different features/aspects almost always are runtime determined.

Do you happen to know what Numpy does? Does it also use std::vector?

Numpy is written/implemented using C and python, so it can't use std::vector as std::vector is provided by C++ standard library.
Instead they use malloc, calloc etc.
Memory management in NumPy

I am curious to know how Numpy overcome this issue and hopefully through that I know how these things are handled in compiled languages such as C or C++. Could you please mention how Numpy does it in C?
So far I learned in C++ we need to use std::vector and that in C++ there is no difference between heap and stack.

@MOON They use malloc etc as mentioned in the answer. I've also provided a link to the reference where it explains that in more details.
